# C++ Priority Queue Declaration

Tags: c++, heap, priority-queue

I'm looking at a declaration of a priority queue in C++ but I don't quite understand it.

```
priority_queue<string, vector<string>,function<bool(string,string)>>
min_heap([] (const string& a,const string& b) {return a.size()>=b.size();});
```

What is the purpose of the brackets []? Is that part of the function definition?

Also, would I be able to implement the same thing by using a bool operator?

Comment: Its the capture clause of a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function.

Comment: It's a lambda. Go read a C++ book. Lambdas cannot be fully explained in a few short sentences on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @SamVarshavchik There is, however, documentation for lambdas here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/572/lambdas#t=201702161028176658324

Answer (score 1):

The entire expression

```
[] (const string& a,const string& b) {return a.size()>=b.size();}
```

is a lambda expression. It is an object of an unnamed class that can be called with two string arguments, `a` and `b`, and returns `bool`.

You could also write such a class yourself (in that case, it would have a name):

```
struct Comp {
    bool operator()(const string& a, const string& b) {
        return a.size() > b.size();
    }
};
priority_queue<string, vector<string>, Comp> min_heap;
// a value of type Comp will be value-initialized
```

Note that the comparator must be a strict weak ordering, so you must use `>` instead of `>=`.

If performance matters, it is better to define a named class, because the function call operator can be inlined.